# How to find VB window/form id

Tags: vb6

**Reqirement: Need to close/kill a particular VB Window.**

I heard like on specifying the window name - we can trace the window id and using that id we can kill/close that active window. 
Does this function help me - `HWND ID by (Hwnd ID)`

Please correct me if im wrong and help me on how to find the window id.

Comment: Use spy++  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266023(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: The VB window to be closed is active but it needs to be closed from another VB window/form.

Comment: Does the window have a title?  If so try http://support.microsoft.com/kb/147659

Answer (score 1):

- Here is [how to find a window](http://vb.mvps.org/samples/FindPart/) (and determine its window handle or hWnd) given the caption or part of the caption
- Here is [how to close the window](http://vb.mvps.org/articles/dd200109.asp) once you know the window handle

From Karl Peterson's excellent VB6 website.

Answer (score 0):

use `me.close` or `unload(me)` for closing active window
 to close a form1 from form2, u can use `unload(form1)` or `form1.close`( working in vb.net)

Comment: i need to close the window from another window/form. I believe both me.close and unload(me) will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If the window has a title, you could do something like

```
Private Declare Function FindWIndow Lib "user32" _
    Alias "FindWindowA" _
    (ByVal lpClassName As Any, _
    ByVal lpWindowName As Any) _
    As Long
...
Dim hWnd As Long
Dim strTitle As String
strTitle = "whatever your title is"
hWnd = FindWIndow(vbNullString, strTitle)
If hWnd <> 0 Then
    Debug.Print "Window ID or Handle is " & Hex(hWnd)
Else
    Debug.Print "Cannot find handle"
End If
```